# Mongoose for/await/of loop is `sort` required in Query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, cursor

From documentation of Mongoose there is the [following example](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/querycursor.html#query_Query-Symbol.asyncIterator) about iterating with async/await:

```
// Works without using `cursor()`
for await (const doc of Model.find([{ $sort: { name: 1 } }])) {
  console.log(doc.name);
}
```

Since I am quite new in MongoDB, I want to understand if `[{ $sort: { name: 1 } }]` is required to get the query working or it is only an example.

My goal is to iterate all the documents in a Collection, so I suppose that following code should be fine:

```
// Works without using `cursor()`
for await (const doc of Model.find()) {
  console.log(doc.name);
}
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mongodb 4.2 and older passing an array of objects to `find` will trigger an exception. So if you run:

```
Model.find([{ $sort: { name: 1 } }]).then(...)
```

you will get:

```
ObjectParameterError: Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object
```

However, in MongoDB 4.4, `[{ $sort: { name: 1 } }]` can, in fact, be passed to `find`. However, `$sort` does not actually go into `find` params, but rather should be used like so `Model.find().sort({name: 1})`.

That makes me believe that `[{ $sort: { name: 1 } }]` in the link you supplied is just a placeholder and servers no purpose. So running

```
for await (const doc of Model.find()) {
```

is perfectly fine.